# Error Turning Asp.net Windows Feature On in IIS 7.2

Tags: asp.net, iis

HI guys

I'm completely stuck with this problem.

I have to install asp.net on iis.

I do this turning windows features on, but the aswer is always "An error has occurred. Not all of the features were successfully changed"

Pc asks for a reboot but after that nothing is installed

WPA is not installed, I Tried to reinstall IIS too (that works) but asp.net does not want to turn on

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You need to tell us more about what OS you're using (Vista, Windows 7?).

Answer (score 0):

I got stung with this recently with the same symptoms and steps. The solution here helped:

http://forums.iis.net/p/1174328/1967812.aspx#1967812

Basically, the problem comes up when you install some component that installs or updates the .NET framework on your machine. In my case, I had installed VS2012 and several components.

The link suggests to uninstall and re-install the .NET Framework. For me, it was good enough to repair the .NET 4.5 install, reboot and all problems enabling new window features went away.

Good luck!

Answer (score -2):

If I do recall correctly simply installing the ASP.Net feature does not work, because the Asp.Net feature requires certain other options to be turned on before. Turn these on and then the enabling of the asp.net feature should work. Try googling for the specified options that you need